# how to copy xml and paste in webpage using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xml-parsing

I'm stuck in Selenium automation, where xml is a input i need to paste the XML in text box in browser and need to click submit. it will provide the result after processed. I need to verify the result.

Is this possible to do in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can read the xml file into a string and send the text into the input field.

For Examle:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

//...

String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/path/to/the/file"), "UTF-8")
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(contents);
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table    could u please giveme code how to paste in this text box

Comment: driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table");
// clear the existing text  
driver.findElement(By.id("textareaCode")).clear();

String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("C:\\eclipse\\test.xml"), "UTF-8");
// enter the new text
driver.findElement(By.id("textareaCode")).sendKeys(contents);